# Vim auto line-break

Tags: vim, word-wrap, line-breaks

When I'm writing a long line of text in vim (such as a paragraph in latex), it wraps my text into multiple lines which is good. However, if I then try to navigate these lines with 'j' and 'k' (or the up/down arrows) it will skip the entire paragraph. I fixed this problem by highlighting the paragraph and pressing `gq`. This inserts line breaks at the end of each line.

My question is, is there a way to automate this, so I don't have to keep highlighting text and pressing `gq`?

Comment: Are you asking for the word wrap to auto insert line breaks?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to step back a little and use `gj` and `gk` which go down and up inside wrapped lines.

Since `gj`and `gk` work exactly the same as `j` and `k` in non-wrapped lines you can safely map `j` or `<down>` to `gj` and `k` or `<up>` to `gk` making it all seamless.

-- EDIT --

Yes it doesn't adress Eddy's immediate problem but it solves his original problem (vertical movement in wrapped lines) which led him to a poor workaround that, in turn, put him in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, this is good because I use svn version control for my latex documents, so now diff won't show loads of lines that have changed due to linebreaks and word wrapping.

Answer (score 69):

You can limit the width of a line with the `textwidth` option
(see `:help tw`).

For example, if you want to limit the width to 80 columns, you can use:

```
:set tw=80
```

With this option, when you will type something longer than 80 columns, Vim
will automatically insert a newline character.

Comment: But there's an issue: when adding new words in an existing line, you will have to select paragraph and press `gq` to re-align it. You can automate this by typing `:set fo+=a`.  Read `:help fo` and `:help fo-table` about this.  But, unfortunately, this mode (after `:set fo+=a`) works not very good and has several issues too.

Comment: Also, it doesn't break lines without white space. Just thought it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

These are the mappings I use. They handle all the cases I have encountered up to now.

```
" Modify the up/down keys so that they move per virtual (rather than
" physical) line if a line is displayed wrapped and no count for the
" command has been specified. Always use logical line steps for quickfix
nnoremap <expr> k ((v:count) ? 'k' : ((&buftype == 'quickfix') ? 'k' : 'gk'))
nnoremap <expr> j ((v:count) ? 'j' : ((&buftype == 'quickfix') ? 'j' : 'gj'))
nnoremap <expr> <Up> ((v:count) ? 'k' : ((&buftype == 'quickfix') ? 'k' : 'gk'))
nnoremap <expr> <Down> ((v:count) ? 'j' : ((&buftype == 'quickfix') ? 'j' : 'gj'))
xnoremap k gk
xnoremap j gj
vnoremap <Up> gk
vnoremap <Down> gj

" Move to start and end of virtual line (this will default to normal behaviour
" if the line isn't wrapped)
nnoremap 0 g0
nnoremap <Home> g0
nnoremap ^ g^
nnoremap $ g$
nnoremap <End> g$

" These mappings need to deal with virtual line numbers in 'insert' mode,
" but they need to do it without messing up normal 'completion menu' operation
inoremap <expr> <Up> pumvisible() ? "\<Up>" : "\<C-o>gk"
inoremap <expr> <Down> pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "\<C-o>gj"
```